# Structures with Interface Members and Pointer Receivers

Tags: go

I'm creating a simple sorted binary tree that's immutable (well it should behave like its immutable) and I'm unsure how pointer receivers work when they are passed a structure with interfaces.

Here's how I'm defining my binary tree.

```
type btree interface {
    display(io.Writer)
    add(int) btree
    replace(int, int)//A test to see if we are sharing nodes
}
```

binary tree nodes are defined like:

```
type node struct {
    data  int
    left  btree
    right btree
}
```

and the empty binary tree node

```
type empty struct{}
```

The function and methods

```
func createEmpty() btree {
    return &empty{}
}
```

Methods for the node struct

```
//replace is just a test to see if I'm sharing nodes
func (n *node) replace(value, replacement int) {
    if n.data < value {
        n.left.replace(value, replacement)
    } else if n.data > value {
        n.right.replace(value, replacement)
    } else {
        n.data = replacement
    }
}

func (n *node) add(data int) btree {
    if n.data < data {
        l := &node{n.data, n.left.add(data), n.right}
        return l
    } else if n.data > data {
        r := &node{n.data, n.left, n.right.add(data)}
        return r
    } else {
        return n
    }
}

func (n *node) display(w io.Writer) {
    n.left.display(w)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, n.data)
    n.right.display(w)
}
```

Methods for the empty nodes

```
//replace is just a test to see if I'm sharing nodes
func (*empty) replace(_, _ int) {}

func (e *empty) add(data int) btree {
    en := &node{data, e, e}
    return en
}

func (*empty) display(w io.Writer) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Empty")
}
```

Please note that the code does work as intended but I'm unsure what happens when I pass a structure with interface members to a pointer receiver. Does the interface data-structure get copied but only a shallow copy so the data it points to remains the same? Is there any documentation on what happens to interfaces in this case?

Here's a working copy of the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

func createEmpty() btree {
    return &empty{}
}

type btree interface {
    display(io.Writer)
    add(int) btree
    replace(int, int)
}

type node struct {
    data  int
    left  btree
    right btree
}

func (n *node) replace(value, replacement int) {
    if n.data < value {
        n.left.replace(value, replacement)
    } else if n.data > value {
        n.right.replace(value, replacement)
    } else {
        n.data = replacement
    }
}

func (n *node) add(data int) btree {
    if n.data < data {
        l := &node{n.data, n.left.add(data), n.right}
        return l
    } else if n.data > data {
        r := &node{n.data, n.left, n.right.add(data)}
        return r
    } else {
        return n
    }
}

func (n *node) display(w io.Writer) {
    n.left.display(w)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, n.data)
    n.right.display(w)
}

type empty struct{}

func (*empty) replace(_, _ int) {}

func (e *empty) add(data int) btree {
    en := &node{data, e, e}
    return en
}

func (*empty) display(w io.Writer) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Empty")
}

func main() {
    bt := createEmpty().add(5).add(1).add(8).add(2)
    bt2 := bt.add(7).add(6).add(10).add(9)
    bt.display(os.Stdout)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "\n--->")
    bt2.display(os.Stdout)
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "\n\n--->")
    //The node with 1 should be shared with bt and bt2
    //so if we change bt's node 1 to 4143
    //we should see the change in bt2 too   
    bt.replace(1, 4143)
    bt.display(os.Stdout)//We see the change here, 1 is now 4143
    fmt.Fprintln(os.Stdout, "\n--->")
    bt2.display(os.Stdout)//We see the change here, 1 is now 4143
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this structure:

```
type node struct {
    data  int
    left  btree
    right btree
}
```

and the function `f` with q pointer receiver:

```
func (n *node) f() {}
```

`f` gets a pointer to a `node`. Any changes `f` makes to the node `n` will be reflected on the copy that is used to invoke `f`.

To be more precise, when you call `n.f()` and if `n` is a `*node`, then a copy of that pointer is sent to `f`, which is still pointing to the same object as `n`. If `n` is not a pointer, then `&n` will be sent to `f`.

For your code to work, the left and right `btree` interfaces should also containg `*node`s, not `node`s (you already did this correctly). This is because if you call, for instance, `node.left.replace`, you want the value in the `node.left` to be replaced. If you had a value-receiver for `replace` function, then when you call `node.left.replace` a copy of that left node will be sent to the `replace` function as a receiver, and the modifications won't be visible on the `node.left` node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first two paragraphs 'of your reply' makes sense but I'm lost on the last one(the last paragraph). Are you talking about the left and right branches in(for example) the add method for node?

Comment: I think I need some remedial work with interfaces and value/pointer receivers. Quick! To the Google cave.